# compile view and data to import it in an other page angular

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to create a dashboard on my home page. So all full views selected must be display on my home page in blocks.

My understanding was that i need to use $compile, to compile all views. But i can't access each controller of each view (no loop in my ng-repeat).

```js
'use strict';

angular
.module('webuiApp')
.directive('dashboardList', function($templateRequest, $compile) {
  return {
    controllerAs: 'endpoints',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      $templateRequest('views/endpoints.html').then(function (html) {
        element.html(html);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

My templateUrl : views/endpoints.html contains a ng-repeat and my result compile template is unable to recover data of the view controller (no data binding).

It is the right way ? What's wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to use <div ui-view> like described here: Multiple Named Views · angular-ui/ui-router Wiki · GitHub https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views  ; maybe this could help you.. In each ui-view you would be able to access the specific controllers

Comment: Thanks for your link but i don't use ui-router, it is like your example i need to display views on blocks on my home page without ui-router.

Comment: You could create directives and send the required data via scope variables and set the binding to 2-way binding ('='), if you need the data to be updated from the parent scope to the isolated directive scope and back to the parent scope

Comment: Can you give me link or an example ?

Comment: You could have a look on this article: http://www.journaldev.com/7572/angularjs-isolate-scope-two-way-binding-tutorial-example or from original AngularJS docu: AngularJS: Tutorial: 4 - Two-way Data Binding https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04